# Why is link(object) faster when the target collection is excluded?

Tags: python, scripting, data-blocks

I stumbled upon a neat discovery and I don't understand why it works. Starting with a blend file only containing an object called 'Cube' and the default collection, I tested this function to see if I could make blender copy objects faster(I know about the array modifier, but I can't use that for my purposes):

```
import bpy
import time

def linkobjects(basemesh, coll, N):
    t0 = time.perf_counter()
    for _ in range(N):
        _name = str(len(bpy.data.objects)) #just to give every object a unique name
        obj = bpy.data.objects.new(_name, basemesh.copy())
        coll.objects.link(obj)
    print(time.perf_counter() - t0)
    return

coll = bpy.data.collections['Collection']
base = bpy.data.objects['Cube'].data.copy()
linkobjects(base, coll, 10000)
```

Normally, it takes about 8.1 seconds. Yet if I exclude the target collection before running it, it only takes 5 seconds!

To my knowledge it is the case that if a collection gets excluded, its contents are written to your disk so it's not in your RAM anymore. Knowing that, it seems weird to me that writing these new objects to an excluded collection is faster, since writing to RAM is generally faster than writing to a file. There are no calls to bpy.ops, so that shouldn't be it either.

Are there things going on in the background that optimize this? What am I missing?

Comment: by "excluded", you mean removing the line `coll.objects.link`?

Comment: @lemon no, I mean exclude the collection from the view layer (the checkbox next to a collection in the outliner)

Comment: ah, ok... no it is approx the same here for me (2.5s vs. 2.4s).

Comment: though, it's a bit faster if creating all objects, appending them in a list, then link each of them in a second time.